# ilegal character '\00a0' error

Tags: java, apache-netbeans

Estoy utilizando java jdk-17.0.5 y apache-netbeans 14. Cuando copio un código de una web me sale un carácter de línea roja (ilegal character '\00a0'). He probado a descargarme diferentes versiones de java y siempre me sale dicho error. He probado en IDE bluej y tambien se produce. A ver si alguien me puede dar información para resolverlo. En este código que muestro, en las líneas en blanco me sale un guión en rojo que me marca el error. Gracias y saludos.

```
public class ProbandoError {
    
public static void main (String args[]){
    int zkia;
    String letra;

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
do{
        System.out.println("Inserte un numero :");
        zkia = sc.nextInt();

        if (zkia%2==0){
            System.out.println("es par!");
        }else{
            System.out.println("es impar!");
        }
        
        System.out.println("[para salir pulsa 'E']:");
        letra = sc.next();
     }while (!letra.equals("E"));
}
```

Comment: Es raro, porque copiando y pegando el codigo que adjuntas no es posible reproducir el error. Prueba copiando el codigo del sitio web, pegalo en un blog de notas, y luego copialo a tu ide. Tambien puedes copiarlo de aqui directamente. Lo he probado en eclipse, en intellij y en netbeans sin ningun error.

Comment: Hola Jaime Menendez. Mira si puedes verificar el nuevo código. Gracias.

Comment: La pregunta se puede [edit] y añadir todo lo que haga falta. Abajo sólo van respuestas

Answer (score 0):

El problema no es de java, el problema es que estás copiando un carácter extraño invisible que java no reconoce. Cambiar la versión de java no va a resolver el problema, puesto que este carácter no es código válido y va a tronar con cualquier versión que utilices.

El nombre del carácter es *no breaking space* ([carácter espacio de no separación](https://unicode-table.com/es/00A0/)) y su código es `U+00A0`. En el mismo Netbeans puedes eliminarlo siguiendo los siguientes pasos:

1. Presiona `Ctrl` + `H` o bien en el menú selecciona `Edit` > `Replace`.
2. Selecciona el ícono de expresiones regulares.
3. Escribe en el textbox de *find* el código del caracter: `\u00A0`. Escribe en el *replace with* un espacio en blanco.
4. Presiona `Replace All` y todos los caracteres extraños serán remplazados por espacios en blanco.

[image: Pasos para eliminar el error del carácter \u00A0 en el código de java]

En caso de usar intellij, el editor automaticamente te señala donde está el caracter, por lo que basta borrarlo manualmente:

[image: no breaking space en IntelliJ]

Comment: Hola Jaime. Lo he podido resolver para la clase pero sigo copiando codigos de diferentes webs y no solo los inserto en netbeans sino también en Bluej y Notepad++ y me sigue pasando lo mismo, incluso hay códigos en los que dicho error me sale en todas las líneas. Por lo tanto, como te comenté debe ser un error de java o windows. No lo sé. seguiré buscando como resolverlo ya que esto anteriomente no me pasaba. Me repararon el ordenador en garantía y solo me trae problemas. Gracias de todas formas pero si alguien sabe se lo agradecería. Saludos cordiales

Comment: @pepote21 eso no tiene que ver con windows o con java, tiene que ver con lo que estas copiando. De cualquier manera esta respuesta le servirá a alguien en el futuro con el mismo problema que quiera arreglar los errores de su codigo. Muy buena suerte en tu búsqueda y espero encuentres lo que buscas.

Comment: Gracias Jaime Menendez.